# Ignore mousePressed

Tags: java, swing, focus, mouseevent

I have a `mouseListener` on my `Component` and I need do the action on `mousePressed` in any case except one: if the `focus` is on another `window` and user clicks on my `Component`.

How can I ignore the `mousePressed` for `Component` if the `focusOwner` was another `window` before `MouseEvent` was fired? The `FocusListener.focusGained` and checking the `focusOwner` at the click moment can't help.

**UPD:** My task is to detect the case when `focusGained` fired on cause of `mousePressed`.

Comment: Does your app create all the windows that can be focused? Or do you want it to ignore mouse events for all other windows in your OS that can be focused?

Comment: Also, this may be a possible XY question. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

Use a `WindowListener` and handle the `windowActivated` and `windowDeactivated` events to register/deregister your MouseListener.

You may need to place the adding of the MouseListener in a SwingUtilities.invokeLater() to make sure the listener is added after the window has focus.

Comment: Interesting way... But if the `mouseListener` is inner for some `JPanel`, I should add the `HierarchyListener` to panel to detect when it will be added to `Window`, then get this `Window` as ancestor, and add the `WindowListener` to this `Window`... ooohh :)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar Problem.
If you implement and register FocusListener you can ask in the focusGained method FocusEvent.getOppositeComponent() and detect if the user has changed the window. After that you can register the Mouslistener and unregister it in the focusLost method.

Comment: That wouldn't help. I can receive `focusGained` by `Alt+Tab` combination.